# Why EclipseLink is adding discriminator column for joined inheritance strategy?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using JOINED inheritance strategy with EclipseLink JPA implementation. I have noticed that EclipseLink is adding discriminator column, named by default DTYPE, to the database schema. I understand, that discriminator is needed for one table inheritance strategy, but why for JOINED strategy?

EclipseLink needs this column because I've got errors after removing it. Is this column added for performance reasons, etc? I am not particularly happy about that since from the point of view of database schema this column is just unnecessary clutter.

Hibernate based JPA does not do anything similar.

Comment: Perhaps you've made an error in your question. You say you understand why if its JOINED but not if its JOINED...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Joined Table Inheritance](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Inheritance#Joined_Table_Inheritance):

> In the joined table inheritance, each
>   class shares data from the root table.
>   In addition, each subclass defines its
>   own table that adds its extended
>   state. The following example shows two
>   tables, PROJECT and L_PROJECT, as well
>   as two classes, Project and
>   LargeProject:
>
> ...

The discriminator column is what determines the type and thus what joined table to use so you need a discriminator column in the parent table.

Comment: Exactly, and this is what I want to understand: why EclipseLink is using this discriminator column - it is not necessary, JOINED strategy is based on foreign keys association between classes.

The JPA spec says that discriminator is optional for JOINED strategy - Hibernate JPA is not using it for instance - and I would like to learn what is the advantage of using it, as EclipseLink does.

Comment: I guess you're referring to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass. ExlipseLink I guess is just explicit in this regard. The discriminator column avoids the problem of doing EXISTS (or similar) checks to find the appropriate subclass. Even if it were optional I'd still use it.

Comment: That makes sense, discriminator surely makes things easier to implement. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Agreed - EclipseLink surely requires a discriminator column for **easier implementation of the library**. It would be great to see some performance benchmark of the Hibernate's solution (which adds "just" some `CASE WHEN ...` into SELECTs) - whether it really is _so much more_ slower when compared to using a discriminator column. Anyway, this SO answer cannot be marked as really useful - it just describes what is being asked. And it is a pity EL doesn't have this - at least, it would surely ease migration for some "legacy" apps.

Comment: What if you cannot change the datamodel and have joined inheritance and you NEED joined inheritance? Then the whole qurey stuff fails with some error `Unknown column 't0.DTYPE' in 'field list' Error Code: 1054 Call: SELECT t0.ID, t0.DTYPE, t0.NAME, t0.parent_id, t1.ID FROM GeoAreas t0, Districts t1 WHERE ((t0.ID = ?) AND ((t1.ID = t0.ID) AND (t0.DTYPE = ?))) ...` and you can basically forget about EclipseLink right away... shouldn't this be fixed?

Comment: @Kawu the same question