# No discriminator column in JOINED inheritance strategy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

**EDIT** - This is solved: ProJPA2 states that some persistence providers implement a JOINED strategy without a discriminator column. Thank you to those who left answers to my question.

---

I have a simple setup that is using the JOINED inheritance strategy, but I am puzzled as to why, contrary to what I am reading about the joined strategy, online as well as in ProJPA2, there is no discriminator column in my generated DDL.

Interestingly there is this question on SO:
[Why EclipseLink is adding discriminator column for joined inheritance strategy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063515/why-eclipselink-is-adding-discriminator-column-for-joined-inheritance-strategy)

which asks, why is eclipselink adding a discriminator column when (in the OP's opinion), it is not necessary.
My small test works fine, the data gets persisted correctly, everything works, which seems to prove that questioner's point, and yet, I have no discriminator column in any of my tables. I have just FKs to the parent (superclass) table from each child (subclass) table.

I am using eclipse, eclipselink 2.5.x, mysql, and it's a Java SE JPA environment, for simplicity. Somewhere I am using hibernate because I'm logging a ton of hibernate stuff eg

```
 17:44:14 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version].logVersion - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
```

but I can't remember where this setting is on the project and I need to leave now.

All insights are appreciated. Thanks.

Code snippets:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;
...
}



@Entity
public abstract class ShoppingOrder extends Order {
    private String shopName;
   ...
}


@Entity
public class SuperMarketShoppingOrder extends ShoppingOrder {

private String supermarketName;
...
}


@Entity
public class EuroSuperMarketShoppingOrder extends SuperMarketShoppingOrder {
    private String country;
...
}
```

Generated DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `shoppingorder` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shopName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `supermarketshoppingorder` (
  `supermarketName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKg6ui4gndl8m9ouut2sb1g8xmm` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `shoppingorder` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `eurosupermarketshoppingorder` (
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK2g6xgprpajjl3msv9rm00gi1f` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `supermarketshoppingorder` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: if it is JOINED then it joins to work out which class/subclass a row represents (hence no real need for a discriminator). You only need a discriminator when a table is holding data for multiple classes (e.g SINGLE_TABLE strategy). And you cannot be using Hibernate AND EclipseLink, so work out what you are using before anything else ...

Comment: "hence no real need for a discriminator" yes I agree. BTW regarding using Hibernate and EclipseLink - I have just opened up the project and remembered that its in the POM that hibernate is specified: the dependencies are hibernate dependencies; meanwhile the JPA facet in eclipse uses eclipselink.

Answer (score 1):

I have just seen this in my ProJPA2 book which clarifies the matter - I am sorry that I did not notice it before:

[image: book]

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is not correct.

You have

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

MappedSuperclass is used to have all fields from the super class in the sub classes and Inheritance is the "real" inheritance mapping.

So you should remove @MappedSuperclass.

But this was not your question.

Have you created queries that are querying on the super class level and also on the sub class level?

Does this work as well?

I could assume that it will not work.

EclipseLink is using the discriminator column to distinguish of which type the subclass is. Hibernate does the same with a case statement.

Please tell me if querying is working. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but `@MappedSuperclass` and `@Inheritance` serve different purposes; `@MappedSuperclass` defines a non-persistable superclass from which subclass entities inherit fields and mappings, whereas `@Inheritance` permits the specification of the inheritance strategy. I have just tried without @MappedSuperclass and as I expected got an exception because I now have a class (Order) with mappings that doesn't have an `@Entity` annotation; it doesn't have an `@Entity` annotation because it's intended to be a mapped superclass - it's not supposed to have its own table.

Comment: The exception is  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: x.y.jpa.entity.ShoppingOrder`

Comment: Yes I have queries (or a query) that works polymorphically: `static TypedQuery<ShoppingOrder> shoppingOrdersQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM ShoppingOrder o", ShoppingOrder.class);`